# Install4j - Batch updating

Tags: java, updates, auto-update, updating, install4j

By default, install4j auto-update functionality allows to download updates one-by-one. I want the user to be able to download all available updates in the background and batch-install *all of them in one step* when download is finished.

Does install4j provide this functionality? How I am able to it?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a partial solution without batch-updating functionallity. Each installer (main program and patch) should check a next update, download it and launch after installation process is completed. You may copy the default updater actions to achive this. Therefore, all updates will be downloaded sequentially. With unattained mode enabled installation of the lastest version could be completly transperent to the user. Also you may have separate updater executable with silent version check to launch this process from java code.

Answer (score 0):

No, install4j does not support this functionality out of the box. install4j assumes that the update installer is a full installer, so the latest installer will be sufficient.

What you describe would be patch installers, but that is not an available concept in install4j.